# SQL: Matching records by set theory

Tags: sql, linkage, cross-join, set-theory

I've been struggling lately with a complex SQL query.
I have the following tables:

```
[dbo].[User] ~ {ID,nickname}  
[dbo].[Property] ~ {ID,title}  
[dbo].[Property_Values] ~ [ID,propertyID,title}  
[dbo].[Property_Values_User_Linkage] ~ {UserID,PropertyID,valueID}
```

It's basically a project in which a user chooses values for each property. Each property can be single-value or multi-value. For instance, user might choose multiple values for Property {ID=1,title=Hobbies} but must choose a single value for Property {ID=2,title=HairColor}.

Using another table - [dbo].[Search_Property_Values_User_Linkage] - {UserID,PropertyID,valueID} I'm choosing what properties I want and I expect to find matching users. BUT, If I haven't chosen a value (or multi-value) for, let's say HairColor, I should get all users (since I don't want to filter by HairColor).

So far it's easy, but the problem I can't seems to solve is the case where there are multi-values ahead or no user defined values. For example, I want all users with HairColor=Brown and Hobbies IN(basketball,football).

I can retrieve all users who match one of the terms (and those who have other properties, since I haven't chosen to filter them) but I can't get only the users who *absolutely* match my criteria.

To put code into words, let's just say I need all users who:

- Match *ALL* property-value that I've chosen
- Might have other properties, such as EyesColor, but since I haven't chosen a filtering value, they might be retrieved as well.
- Might not have any property set at all, but since I haven't chosen a value for this property, they are VALID!
- Match all selected properties as group, not just one property that I've chosen (users who likes basketball but have "red" for their
  HairColor are INVALID!

I came across with a solution in which I create a virtual table which "completes" non-chosen values by bits. For instance (not actual code):

```
DECLARE @isMatches bit  
SET @isMatches=0    
if [propertyIsChosen]=1  
{    
 if [userInProperty]=1 SET @isMatches=1   
}  
else SET isMatches=1
```

I basically CROSS-JOIN [Property] WITH [User]
and LEFT-OUTER-JOIN the rest of the tables to match selections.
I get all users and their match to a property. This is not good enough since I get users who have Brown hair, those who like basketball/football, but not those who matches to both (and of course any other undefined property by me).
This is heavy, but it's the what I got so far to analyze the problem.

I would appreciate any help. I think I'm missing something from my math classes, 10 years ago...

EDIT: db pic: http://i51.tinypic.com/2n1cfwg.png

Comment: Is the number of the properties (either single or multiple values) fixed? I mean is there going to be added or removed a property later?

Comment: And please tell me are the single value properties going to change to multivalue properties in any time? Also do all users have the same number of properties? In addition do the existence of properties makes sence without the existence of users? I mean if no users entered yet, does it make sense to have records that say property1:value=hobby, property2:value=children etc?

Comment: Yes, a single value might be changed into a multi-values. All users can select the same properties, but might choose to set only few and not all of them. Yes, properties are displayed in user's profile where he/she can sets these, there is no relative connection between the two. Thanks!!!

Comment: What are your FOREIGN KEYs?. Specifically, are you using identifying FOREIGN KEYs (i.e. are you transferring parent primary keys into child primary keys)?

Comment: Of course. Each table which stores propertyID actually links to [dbo].[Property].[ID]. Each table which stores valueID actually links to [dbo].[Property_Values].[ID]. Etc... but I don't quite get what does it have to do with the query I'm looking for (?)

Comment: OK, let me be more specific - do you have this referential integrity: `ALTER TABLE Property_Values_User_Linkage ADD CONSTRAINT Property_Values_User_Linkage_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (valueID, PropertyID) REFERENCES Property_Values (ID, propertyID)`? I'm also interested in what is going on between `Property_Values` and `Property` - is this an identifying relationship or not? Perhaps it would be best if you edited your question to include the precise specification of all your referential integrities. Let us first figure out if your data model is correct before we construct a query for it.

Comment: I am sure it is a redudant-inconsistent schema design, if you want to try a new design let us know

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, I'm willing to hear any design suggestions, I hope this will clear things up: http://i51.tinypic.com/2n1cfwg.png and I don't have that specific key linking, I just linked KEY to KEY, not both of the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Data Model

From you comment, I see that you have some other property-related tables that you have not mentioned in your question. I'm gonna assume we can ignore these for now and just concentrate on representing property values, which can be done by a simplified model below:

[image]

DDL SQL (MS SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE [USER] (
    USER_ID int NOT NULL,
    NICKNAME nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_USER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (USER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE USER_PROPERTY_VALUE(
    USER_ID int NOT NULL,
    PROPERTY_NAME nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PROPERTY_VALUE_NO int NOT NULL,
    PROPERTY_VALUE nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_USER_PROPERTY_VALUE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        USER_ID,
        PROPERTY_NAME,
        PROPERTY_VALUE_NO
    )
);

ALTER TABLE USER_PROPERTY_VALUE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USER_PROPERTY_VALUE_USER FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID)
REFERENCES [USER] (USER_ID);
```

A multi-value is represented by several rows in USER_PROPERTY_VALUE, sharing the same PROPERTY_NAME but each having a distinct PROPERTY_VALUE_NO.

The following example data...

```
Rob:   HairColor={brown}, Hobby={basketball,football}
Bob:   HairColor={brown}, Hobby={basketball}
Steve: Hobby={basketball,football}
```

...is represented in the database like this:

USER:

```
USER_ID NICKNAME
1       Rob
2       Bob
3       Steve
```

USER_PROPERTY_VALUE:

```
USER_ID PROPERTY_NAME   PROPERTY_VALUE_NO   PROPERTY_VALUE
1       HairColor       1                   brown
1       Hobby           1                   basketball
1       Hobby           2                   football
2       HairColor       1                   brown
2       Hobby           1                   basketball
3       Hobby           1                   basketball
3       Hobby           2                   football
```

### Example Queries

Select users with brown hair color:

```
SELECT *
FROM [USER]
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM USER_PROPERTY_VALUE 
        WHERE
            USER_PROPERTY_VALUE.USER_ID = [USER].USER_ID
            AND PROPERTY_NAME = 'HairColor'
            AND PROPERTY_VALUE = 'brown'
    )
```

Result:

```
USER_ID NICKNAME
1       Rob
2       Bob
```

Select users whose hobbies include both basketball and football:

```
SELECT *
FROM [USER]
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM USER_PROPERTY_VALUE 
        WHERE
            USER_PROPERTY_VALUE.USER_ID = [USER].USER_ID
            AND PROPERTY_NAME = 'Hobby'
            AND PROPERTY_VALUE = 'basketball'
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM USER_PROPERTY_VALUE 
        WHERE
            USER_PROPERTY_VALUE.USER_ID = [USER].USER_ID
            AND PROPERTY_NAME = 'Hobby'
            AND PROPERTY_VALUE = 'football'
    )
```

Result:

```
USER_ID NICKNAME
1       Rob
3       Steve
```

Select users whose hair color is brown and hobbies include both basketball and football.

```
SELECT *
FROM [USER]
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM USER_PROPERTY_VALUE 
        WHERE
            USER_PROPERTY_VALUE.USER_ID = [USER].USER_ID
            AND PROPERTY_NAME = 'HairColor'
            AND PROPERTY_VALUE = 'brown'
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM USER_PROPERTY_VALUE 
        WHERE
            USER_PROPERTY_VALUE.USER_ID = [USER].USER_ID
            AND PROPERTY_NAME = 'Hobby'
            AND PROPERTY_VALUE = 'basketball'
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM USER_PROPERTY_VALUE 
        WHERE
            USER_PROPERTY_VALUE.USER_ID = [USER].USER_ID
            AND PROPERTY_NAME = 'Hobby'
            AND PROPERTY_VALUE = 'football'
    )
```

Result:

```
USER_ID NICKNAME
1       Rob
```

Etc, etc...

### Querying Based on the Contents of Another Table

Let's say you have a table that contains the filter criteria:

```
CREATE TABLE PROPERTY_FILTER (
    PROPERTY_NAME nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PROPERTY_VALUE nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PROPERTY_FILTER PRIMARY KEY (PROPERTY_NAME, PROPERTY_VALUE)
)
```

The following query will return only users that fulfill the criteria currently contained in that table:

```
SELECT *
FROM [USER] U
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT F.PROPERTY_NAME, F.PROPERTY_VALUE
        FROM PROPERTY_FILTER F
        EXCEPT
        SELECT P.PROPERTY_NAME, P.PROPERTY_VALUE
        FROM USER_PROPERTY_VALUE P
        WHERE P.USER_ID = U.USER_ID
    )
```

In plain English: if there is a filter property that is not also users's property, ignore that user.

BTW, this will not work in concurrent multi-user environment - you'll need to introduce an additional field in the PROPERTY_FILTER table to identify the "session", or use [temporary tables](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/temporary-tables-ms-sql-server/) (if you don't require persistence).

Comment: Thanks for the profound answer! However, making an exists query for each property doesn't allow dynamic queries and of course, inefficient for a mass application. As I mentioned, we have yet another table: [dbo].[Search_Property_Values_User_Linkage] which is a replica of USER_PROPERTY_VALUE, but represents the properties I want to filter.  I'm looking for the exact idea you implemented, just dynamic (using joins between two tables, for example). Thanks again, I really appreciate that!

Comment: @S_S Please clarify what you mean "dynamic"? Are you actually referring to the query with bound parameters (and whose SQL text does not need to change)? Or are you referring to filtering based on the contents of another table (and if so, how do you intend to make it work in a multi-user environment)? BTW, each of these sub-queries is potentially very efficient (if indexes are constructed correctly) - this is in fact an emulation what a NESTED LOOP join would do. The performance may become a problem if you have large amount of them (i.e. you search on many properties). Is that the case?

Comment: @S_S BTW, your model seems to allow for data inconsistencies - e.g. Property_Values_User_Linkage.PropertyID can be different from Property_Values.propertyID (linked through Property_Values_User_Linkage.valueID), so you should consider using identifying relationships regardless of the query.

Comment: "are you referring to filtering based on the contents of another table" and "The performance may become a problem if you have large amount of them (i.e. you search on many properties). Is that the case?" - yes for both. By dynamic I meant to compare tables - since each one may have additional data in the future.

Comment: @S_S Please see the "Querying Based on the Contents of Another Table" edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand there isn't a pure query to do the job (I don't want to use temp tables). Well, as a last option I may have to process data using IIS (aspx) and store it in a new table (userID,matchUserID). Each [x] hours, re-process and re-insert values.